# Flexbox - Don't move centered columns if width changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a frustrating problem with the otherwise great flexbox capabilities. I have the following layout with a centered column

[image]

The problem is, if one of the texts in the row grows or shrinks, then the FB/IG icons will not be in the same column line anymore. See what happens:

[image]

How can I achieve for variable width texts to not make the element grow to the left, but make the FB and IG icons actually stay in the same line no matter the variable texts??

Here is the code

```css
.test-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test-link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <img class="test-img" src="path" />
  <div class="test-links">
    <a class="test-link">
      <i class="fb"></i>
      <span>Test</span>
    </a>
    <a class="test-link">
      <i class="ig"></i>
      <span>LongerText</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you know that this would mean that the `fb` icon in your example will have a lot of space to the right of it until the `Text` ? is that what you want ?

Comment: You can try giving the icon " float:left; " and see what happens

Comment: Are you have tried table format...??? Try to put a table. Icons in one column and their texts in one column. So, HTML will ensure there alignment.. Try to use <table>
   <tr>
       <td> // FB Icon </td> <td> FB </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td > // Icon </td> <td> Text </td>
   </tr>
</table>

Comment: Make the `.test-links` container `inline-flex`, and adjust the content of the links to the left instead of center …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.test-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test-link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  width:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.test-wrapper
{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <img class="test-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
  <div class="test-links">
    <a class="test-link">
      <i class="fb fa fa-facebook"></i>
      <span>Test</span>
    </a>
    <a class="test-link">
      <i class="ig fa fa-instagram"></i>
      <span>LongerText</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20" />` instead of icons, so to render something. `position: absolute` for text does the job.

[Following MDN's definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **[position] absolute**: the element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

... so `left:100%` moves it to the left for whole width of parent's element, which is only an icon. You can create a distance between icon/image and text using `margin-left` for text. `position: relative` for link makes it a hook for position of absolute child.

You can adjust precise values.

#### Snippet

```css
.test-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.test-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.test-link {
  position: relative;
}

.test-link span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <img class="test-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
  <div class="test-links">
    <a class="test-link">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20" />
      <span>Test</span>
    </a>
    <a class="test-link">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20" />
      <span>LongerText</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well a bit too slow :( Still adding the link here [CodePen](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/pZEzMp)

Comment: Post your answer here anyway. StackOverflow is all about different approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer. But great to have different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Since, `span` cannot take width, use `p` instead and then add the following class to you code:

```
.test-link p{
  width: 50px;
  height:auto;
  word-break:break-all;
  text-align:left;
}
```

And then you will achieve the desired format.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/mwuyqkcn/7/) is a link to the fiddle supporting this answer.

Here is the snippet:

```css
.test-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test-link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.test-link p{
  width:50px;
  height:auto;
  word-break:break-all;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <div class="test-links">
    <a class="test-link">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
      <p>Test</p>
    </a>
    <a class="test-link">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
      <p>LongerText</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I like this approach, however, the longer the word, the more the `test-link` element moves to the left. I would like it to stay where it: is centered below the image.

Comment: Can you please explain this question again, havent got it clearly

Comment: In that case, you can give the width of the `p` tag in `vw` instead of `px`, that way, the width of the `p` tag will be according to the width of the screen.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could accept more answers, but I really appreciate your effort!